# Read more button doesn't work in mobile theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

The problem here is read more button doesn't work in mobile theme on my Wordpress blog

my site: abood250.com

```
    /* =Mobile Styling
----------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .pull-right {
    float: none !important;

  }
  .pull-left {
    float: none !important;
  }



  .site-info, .copyright {
      text-align: right;

  }

  .footer-nav.nav, .copyright {
    float: none;

  }

  .site-content {
    width: 100%;
}

  .flex-caption {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar > .container .navbar-brand {
    margin: 0;

  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 15px 10px;
  }

  #footer-area {
    display: none;
  }

  .entry-content {
     margin: 0;

    }



}
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Please see [ask]. Right now you just show us some CSS.

Comment: @Rizier123 The Meaning of that is clicking doesn't work on mobile however, it works on desktop theme also I added the page

Comment: You need to show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to fact that

```
    <div class="content-area col-md-8" id="primary">
      ...   
    </div>
```

and

```
    <div class="widget-area col-md-4" id="secondary" role="complementary">
      ....      
    </div>
```

are overlapping in mobile view. You can verify it via inspect element tool.

To solve the problem, you have to use media queries to apply the followinf rule only to desktop screen (and maybe tablet), but not for phones.

```
 .side-pull-right #primary {
    float: right;
 }
```